# Tricky (for me) Regex Replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ and I want to replace all the strings in this file that end in 'Field' with _.

For example: dbNameField => _dbName, or docIdField => _docId.

Should be easy for experience Regexers, but I'm not there yet.

I used the string `\w*Field\b` to successfully find all the strings I want to change.

I tried `\w*\b` to change it to, but got `w*b`.

Comment: I used the string "\w\*Field\b" to successfully find all the strings I want to change. I tried "\w*\b" to change it to, but got "w*b"--kinda dumb, perhaps, but ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `\w*` part into a capturing group and then replace the pattern with `_$1`:

*Find What*: `(\w*)Field\b`
*Replace with*: `_$1`

**Pattern details**

- `(\w*)` - Group 1 capturing zero or more (due to `*`, if you need to match one or more, use `+` quantifier)
- `Field\b` - a `Field` substring with a word boundary after.

The `$1` is the backreference to the contents inside Group 1.

[image]